# Python login to website with requests returns 403

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, http-status-code-403

I am trying to login to https://www.zalando-lounge.com/#/ using `requests`. The problem is that website returns 403 status code.

This is my code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.zalando-lounge.com/onboarding-api/login'

payload = {
    'email': 'my_email',
    'password': 'my_password',
    'onlyLogin': 'true'
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.text)
```

In response I get 403 status code and this:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>

You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;failover&#46;www&#46;zalando&#45;lounge&#46;de&#47;waf&#95;deny&#95;lounge&#46;html&#63;" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;379ec817&#46;1608234674&#46;21c18108
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: When you look at the actual request body versus one that gets sent via the browser, are there any differences between them?

Comment: your request is getting denied, are you sure your allowed to access the site?

Comment: @RandomDavis is request body a thing i send in payload dict? If so, they're the same.

Comment: @reece I can login using browser.

Comment: @Soutparl no, I meant the whole request, i.e. `r.request`, which contains the payload. And I meant compare that to the actual equivalent browser request that you'd get from, like, the browser debug tools.

Comment: You are most likely missing some headers or cookies

Comment: @RandomDavis ok so in my request there is no Refer, Content, Origin, DNT and Cookie value in headers. Also in a browser in headers there is "POST /onboarding-api/login HTTP/2" and mine is "POST /onboarding-api/login HTTP/1.1".